# Kill process on first (and any) output

Tags: bash

Is it possible to kill command on its first output?
Here is example of command

```
strace -e trace=desc ./a.out 2>&1 | grep "open\|something_else"
```

So I want to kill `strace` and/or `a.out` processes in case if grep finds something.

Is it possible in bash (or may be in python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it to exit like this using awk:

```
strace -e trace=desc ./a.out 2>&1 | awk '/open|something_else/ {print; exit}'
```